# JQuery Click Event not Trigerred

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating my own customize javascript calendar. The shell calendar is generated successfully and looked good. However, I am not able to triggered onclick event. When I click on the button, it does not do anything.

**Here is how the Html is being generated:**

```
var GenerateCalendar = function(){
    var calDiv = $('#cal');
    var cal = new Calendar(8,2009);
    cal.generateHTML();
    var calHtml = cal.getHTML();
    calDiv .html(calHtml);
}
```

**I tried adding each of the click event below to the leftArrow anchor with no success:**

```
$('#cal').delegate('click','leftArow', function () {
    console.log('you click me.');
});

$('#leftArrow').on('click', function () {
    console.log('you click me.');
});

$('#cal').on('click','leftArrow', function () {
    console.log('you click me.');
});
```

**GenerateCalendar created the below html file**

```html
<table class="calendar-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="#" id="leftArrow">
           <span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span>
          </a>
       </th>
       <th colspan="5">
         <span id="month">September</span>&nbsp;
         <span id="year">2009</span>
       </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#" id="rightArrow">
              <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
            </a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calendar-header">
      <td class="calendar-header-day">SUN</td>
      <td class="calendar-header-day">MOM</td>
      <td class="calendar-header-day">TUE</td>
      <td class="calendar-header-day">WED</td>
      <td class="calendar-header-day">THU</td>
      <td class="calendar-header-day">FRI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-day"></td>
      <td class="calendar-day"></td>
      <td class="calendar-day">1</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">2</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">3</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">4</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-day">6</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">7</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">8</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">9</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">10</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">11</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-day">13</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">14</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">15</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">16</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">17</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">18</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-day">20</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">21</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">22</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">23</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">24</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">25</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-day">27</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">28</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">29</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">30</td>
      <td class="calendar-day">31</td>
      <td class="calendar-day"></td>
      <td class="calendar-day"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please format your HTML, so we can see what's going on! Also, delegate has long been deprecated...

Comment: `$('#cal').on('click','#leftArrow', function () {`  You forgot about # before id.

Comment: Also, you probably meant `leftArrow` not `leftArow`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target an id, just use `#`

```
$('#cal').on('click','#leftArrow', function () {
    console.log('you click me.');
});
```

The same in delegate

```
$('#cal').delegate('#leftArow', 'click', function () {
    console.log('you click me.');
});
```

Comment: `delegate` sig is different: `$('#cal').delegate('#leftArow', 'click', function () {...});`

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff . Edited

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating the calendar after your doing the binding,
if calendar doesn't exist yet you won't be able to bind the left arrow click.
You should bind to an element that is always there like the body, espically if your using an independent id as a selector

```
$('body').on('click','#leftArrow', function () {
   console.log('you click me.');
});
```

Comment: I forgot the # before the leftArrow which was causing the problem.

Comment: Glad you found the problem, hope it my answer helped in some sort of way